# Move row to top of table

Tags: r, dataframe

I am wondering if it is possible to move one row from bottom to top of a table. When I use the code I have so far,

```
dt[nrow(dt)+1,] <- rbind(c("","","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","1X","2X","6X","3X",""), dt)
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmjeS.png)
With this code, I get a new row at the bottom of my table. If I change the "+1" to "-22" the row goes to the top of the [table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT5aR.png). If I make this change, a row gets deleted off of the bottom of my table. Any help with why this might be happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways but here are two easy ones:

```
a <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 20:29)
a <- a[c(10,1:9),]
a

##Or

a <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 20:29)
a <- rbind(a[10,],a[1:9,])
a
```